# Defining Variable Within if/fi statement In A Unix Bash Script

Tags: linux, bash, unix, if-statement, centos

Good Morning All,

Currently, I am trying to define a variable within an if/fi statement in a bash script that checks the current system time and as a result of the current system time, defines a variable:

```
TIME=`date +%h%m%s`

if [ ${TIME} -ge 050000 ]; then RUNHR=00 fi
if [ ${TIME} -ge 110000 ]; then RUNHR=06 fi
if [ ${TIME} -ge 170000 ]; then RUNHR=12 fi
if [ ${TIME} -ge 225900 ]; then RUNHR=18 fi
```

After I do this however, the RUNHR value doesn't stick and is never defined.

Does anyone have any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Number of problems here: (1) Space after `=` on line 1.  (2) Missing `;` after setting `RUNHR` value on all lines.

Comment: Hi devnull. Thanks for replying! The space after = on line 1 was a typo when I was trying to set the coding into the thread "code" layout. Also, I added the ; after every RUNHR value and now I getting an "integer expression expected" error.

Comment: The `date` format is incorrect.  Say `TIME=$(date +%H%M%S)` instead.

Comment: Thanks devnull! That completely fixed the issue and my bash script is running smoothly now! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linux Scripting is not syntax flexible.

first of all you must use HM rather hm , small hm will give you date in string.

This is tested.

```
TIME=`date +%H%M%s`

if [ ${TIME} -ge 050000 ]; then 
RUNHR=00 
fi
if [ ${TIME} -ge 110000 ]; then 
RUNHR=06 
fi
if [ ${TIME} -ge 170000 ]; then 
RUNHR=12 
fi
if [ ${TIME} -ge 225900 ]; then 
RUNHR=18 
fi

echo $RUNHR
```

Thanks

Suyash Jain
http://linuxhacks.in